# Detached object reattached with cascade=CascadeType.MERGE + @Version = Staleobjectexception

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have always understood that marking a method with cascade=CascadeType.MERGE would lead any detached entities to be reattached which may involve a roundtrip to the database

```
public class PollVote{
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="FK_UserId",nullable=true,updatable=false)
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

In this case, the User class has an @Version property

```
public class User{
@Column
@Version
@JsonIgnore
public Date getLastUpdate() {
    return lastUpdate;
}
```

However, in some instances, I'm getting a StaleObjectStateException. I realize that this must be occurring because the user object I'm passing I just take from the session and it may therefore be stale. Which in this case is largely irrelevant because all that is needed is the id of the user object to save the pollVote.

My first question is: on a cascade=CascadeType.MERGE: if you pass in a stale object with an @Version attribute, shouldn't Hibernate refresh the object from the database in stead of throw a staleobjectstateexception?

My second question is: why is a StaleObjectStateException thrown when all that is needed is the id, which is immutable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're merging a PollVote and have configured Hibernate to cascade the merge to the User of the PollVote. So hibernate checks that the state of the User it's merging has not been modified by some other transaction in the meantime. That's the whole point of optimitic locking.

It seems like you actually don't want to merge the state of the User when merging a PollVote. In that case, remove the cascade=MERGE attribute, and simply use `EntityManager.getReference()` to get a reference to the user you want the PollVote attached to.

Comment: I largely use CascadeType.MERGE to reattach detach objects. Seems like I'm getting some unwanted bonus here. I'm just wondering how to use EntityManager.getReference in a sane manner. It looks like if you know you're merging in something that's just a reference you could use this as a kind of alternative reattach method. It just feels like that should/could be handled by Hibernate automatically. I wonder if this is the only way?